# How to check against domain in Array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, preg-match, string-matching

I've been at this all afternoon and I can not figure this out. I've thrown maybe 6 different solutions at this and I can not get this to work.

**Situation:** Upload page. We have a array that parses and matches a metafile against a local variable that holds the desired domain name. We want both to match. So this fails the check and it assigns **"external=yes"** thinking the domains have nothing to do with each other and moves on with the rest of the script. **We very much want external = no when the domain is properly matched against the local variable holding the 'same' domain name (with url parameters)**.

So it checks in the array (parses file) against the variables wrapped in  **!in_array**. Say, domain.com/somepage.html in our local variable, it can not match because of /somepage.html

At default the code is as follows:

```
    $match_urls   = explode(",", strtolower($siteconfig["urls_list"]));        
    $FileInfo     = array();
    $FileInfo     = ParseFile("$file_dir/$file_name");
    $urls         = $FileInfo[0];
    $filehash     = $FileInfo[1];
    $creationdate = $FileInfo[2];
    $internalname = $FileInfo[3];

    if (!in_array($urls, $match_urls, 1)) {
        $external = 'yes'; <-- domain fails to match, so we only get this (not good)
    } else {
        $external = 'no'; <-- We need this for matched domain (parsed & local variable)
    }
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
function CheckUrls($domain){
        $domain = "http://website.com/announce";
if (preg_match('{^http://[\w\.]*website.com/}i', $domain)) {
        return true;
} else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And have tried many many variations in this:

```
if (!in_array($urls, CheckUrls() === true, 1)) {
        $external = 'yes';
} else {
        $external = 'no';
}
```

I've also tried passing:

```
    $domain = "http://website.com/somepage.html";
    $checkit = preg_match('{^http://[\w\.]*website.com/}i', $domain));
```

To:

```
if (!in_array($urls, $checkit, 1)) {          
$external = 'yes';
} else {
$external = 'no';
}
```

I've var_dumped my way through the last 4 hours and I've tried and tried, and tested and tested.. I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

This works perfectly in match:

```
preg_match('{^http://[\w\.]*website.com/}i', $domain)
```

**But I can't implement it to !in_array()** and its driving me nuts. I've tried passing true/false/null to no avail.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The CheckUrls doesnt make sense since it's returning a boolean instead of an array. Preg_match function will return 1 or 0 in case of any match(or no) or false if something happens, instead of the match itself. If you want to a get a list of the matches, you're going to have to pass a third param(an array) and return that to be used on the in_array function, something like this:

```php
function checkUrls($domain)
{
     $matches = [];
     preg_match('{^http://[\w\.]*website.com/}i', $domain, $matches);
     return $matches;
}
```

Then, just do:

```php
$external = 'no';

if (!in_array($urls, checkUrls($domain), true)) {          
   $external = 'yes';
}
```

Refer to this to use preg_match properly: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php